# How to declare extern class pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, header, extern

The following is declared variable in the cpp file but I get an error, so I have conducted a research and I found that I need to declare it in the header file. therefore how can I declare and an extern class pointer in the header file

```
 extern AnimationController* g_pAnimationController;
```

Comment: Just the way you do it. But, you need  a forward declaration `class AnimationController;`, first. (You can put it in the source file, without using a header, although it will lead to maintenance issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like how you have there. Ex:

```
// In header file:
// Declare the pointer with external linkage.
extern int* my_global_int;

// In source file:
// Define the pointer so that the linker can link stuff together with the code
// referencing the `my_global_int` symbol.
int* my_global_int = 0;
```

For classes and structs, if the type is unknown, then we need a forward declaration so that the compiler has some idea of what it is. But we can combine it with the declaration, like so:

```
// In header file:
extern class AnimationController* g_pAnimationController;
```

Or written more verbosely:

```
// In header file:
class AnimationController;
extern AnimationController* g_pAnimationController;
```

Update for comment question:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

// Declare AnimationCallback
extern std::map<std::string, AnimationCallback*> g_mCallbackMap;
```

Comment: `class std::map <std::string, AnimationCallback*> g_mCallbackMap;` gives error. How can I fix it

Comment: Easy way: #include <map> and take that class keyword out. Harder way and not recommended: `namespace std {template <class Key, class Val, class Pred, class Alloc> class map;}` and we still have to take that `class` specifier out.

Comment: Put an update in the answer. We also need to declare this `AnimationCallback*` if you don't have it. The compiler has to understand every symbol it sees, otherwise it's like, "What the heck is `AnimationCallback`"? "What the heck is `std::map`"? So we have to teach it what it is at a basic level, hence your forward declarations and function prototypes and so on. We don't have to teach it everything all the time, like we only have to give it the prototype of a function, not the definition (not the full code implementing it) inside a header, but we do need to give it some idea.